# Cómo hacer interpolación a una nube condensada de puntos

Tags: python, scipy

cordial saludo, el presente mensaje es para preguntar cómo puedo realizar un spline o interpolación polinómica con alguna de las librerías de python, ya que al intentar hacerla con el polinomio de Lagrange de la librería scipy me aparece que no es capaz de procesar dichos puntos, (sake naan) a continuación adjunto dicho código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange

xd=[0,1.3,2.7,3.8,4.5,5.7,6.4,7.4,8,9,10.5,10.5,10.6,11.1,12.1,13.2,14.2,15.2,15.8,16.6,17.3,17.7,17.8,20.2,20.4,22,22.3,22.5,22.7,23,23.6,23.7,23.9,24.1,  24.5,25.84,27.2,27.4,27.5,27.7,28.2,28.3,28.6,28.7,28.8,30.7,32.4,32.5,32.8,32.9,33.2,33.2,33.5,33.6,34.5,34.7,34.8,35.15,35.4,35.5,35.6,37.1,37.2,37.6,37.6,37.6,38,38.4,38.4,38.7,39.4,39.6,41.3,44.1,44.4,44.5,44.8,44.9,44.9,45.9,46.1,46.4,46.5,46.5,  46.6,46.9,  47,47.1,47.3,47.5,47.7,47.9,48,48.1,48.4,48.5,48.5,48.9,49.1,49.3,49.3,49.6,49.7,50.1,50.1,50.1,50.2,50.5,50.6,50.8,50.9,51.7,51.7,52,52.1,52.2,52.3,52.6,53.7,53.8,53.8,54.2,54.3,54.5,54.6,54.8,54.9,]
yd=[2184.77,2184.47,2184.23,2184.02,2183.83,2183.53,2183.33,2182.97,2182.76,2182.28,2181.52,2181.51,2181.51,2181.28,2180.85,2180.48,2180.15,2179.84,2179.7  ,2179.54,2179.42,2179.37,2179.36,2179.18,2179.16,2178.9,2178.88,2178.86,2178.86,2178.84,2178.79,2178.75,2178.71,2178.66,2178.54,2178.08,2177.62,2177.57,2177.53,2177.48,2177.4,2177.39,2177.38,2177.38,2177.38,2177.39,2177.34,2177.34,2177.34,2177.35,2177.37,2177.38,2177.41,2177.43,2177.71,2177.81,2177.862,2178.05,2178.17,2178.22,2178.25,2179.01,2179.07,2179.26,2179.28,2179.29,2179.5,2179.7,2179.73,2179.87,2180.21,2180.32,2181.13,2182.44,2182.57,2182.6,2182.69,2182.71,2182.72,2182.87,2182.91,2183.01,2183.03,2183.04,2183.07,2183.17,2183.2,2183.26,2183.33,2183.4,2183.48,2183.52,2183.57,2183.61,2183.71,2183.75,2183.76,2183.9,2183.96,2184.08,2184.09,2184.22,2184.28,2184.42,2184.43,2184.44   ,2184.47,2184.62,2184.66,2184.75,2184.82,2185.22,2185.26,2185.38,2185.45,2185.47,2185.5,2185.6,2185.89,2185.9,2185.92,2186.05,2186.08,2186.13,2186.17,2186.23,2186.23]  

ywater=2182
n=10
z=ywater-np.min(yd)
deltazi=z/n
xmin=np.min(xd)
xmax= np.max(xd)
ymin=np.min(yd)
poly = lagrange(xd, yd)

ywater=2182
n=10
z=ywater-np.min(yd)
deltazi=z/n
xmin=np.min(xd)
xmax= np.max(xd)
ymin=np.min(yd)
poly = lagrange(xd, yd)

print(poly)

plt.plot(xd,yd, '+',color='green')
plt.plot(xd,poly(xd), '+',color='green')
plt.axhline(ywater)
plt.show()
```

Agradezco su ayuda si conocen de otro método o una mejor forma óptima para desarrollarlo.

Answer (score 0):

espero que te valga esto.

```html
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xd=[0,1.3,2.7,3.8,4.5,5.7,6.4,7.4,8,9,10.5,10.5,10.6,11.1,12.1,13.2,14.2,15.2,15.8,16.6,17.3,17.7,17.8,20.2,20.4,22,22.3,22.5,22.7,23,23.6,23.7,23.9,24.1,  24.5,25.84,27.2,27.4,27.5,27.7,28.2,28.3,28.6,28.7,28.8,30.7,32.4,32.5,32.8,32.9,33.2,33.2,33.5,33.6,34.5,34.7,34.8,35.15,35.4,35.5,35.6,37.1,37.2,37.6,37.6,37.6,38,38.4,38.4,38.7,39.4,39.6,41.3,44.1,44.4,44.5,44.8,44.9,44.9,45.9,46.1,46.4,46.5,46.5,  46.6,46.9,  47,47.1,47.3,47.5,47.7,47.9,48,48.1,48.4,48.5,48.5,48.9,49.1,49.3,49.3,49.6,49.7,50.1,50.1,50.1,50.2,50.5,50.6,50.8,50.9,51.7,51.7,52,52.1,52.2,52.3,52.6,53.7,53.8,53.8,54.2,54.3,54.5,54.6,54.8,54.9,]
yd=[2184.77,2184.47,2184.23,2184.02,2183.83,2183.53,2183.33,2182.97,2182.76,2182.28,2181.52,2181.51,2181.51,2181.28,2180.85,2180.48,2180.15,2179.84,2179.7  ,2179.54,2179.42,2179.37,2179.36,2179.18,2179.16,2178.9,2178.88,2178.86,2178.86,2178.84,2178.79,2178.75,2178.71,2178.66,2178.54,2178.08,2177.62,2177.57,2177.53,2177.48,2177.4,2177.39,2177.38,2177.38,2177.38,2177.39,2177.34,2177.34,2177.34,2177.35,2177.37,2177.38,2177.41,2177.43,2177.71,2177.81,2177.862,2178.05,2178.17,2178.22,2178.25,2179.01,2179.07,2179.26,2179.28,2179.29,2179.5,2179.7,2179.73,2179.87,2180.21,2180.32,2181.13,2182.44,2182.57,2182.6,2182.69,2182.71,2182.72,2182.87,2182.91,2183.01,2183.03,2183.04,2183.07,2183.17,2183.2,2183.26,2183.33,2183.4,2183.48,2183.52,2183.57,2183.61,2183.71,2183.75,2183.76,2183.9,2183.96,2184.08,2184.09,2184.22,2184.28,2184.42,2184.43,2184.44   ,2184.47,2184.62,2184.66,2184.75,2184.82,2185.22,2185.26,2185.38,2185.45,2185.47,2185.5,2185.6,2185.89,2185.9,2185.92,2186.05,2186.08,2186.13,2186.17,2186.23,2186.23]  
d = {'x' : xd,'y' : yd} #creo diccionario
f=pd.DataFrame(d)  #creo dataset
sns.regplot(x="x", y="y", data=f,order=2); # cambia order dependiendo del grado del polinomio que quieras
plt.show()
```